# Disable cut, copy, paste on UITextField using IBInspectable

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, ibdesignable

Please find the following code which did not work for me.

```
 @IBInspectable var pasteOption: Bool = true {
        didSet {
            func canPerformAction(action: Selector, withSender sender: AnyObject) -> Bool {
                if action == "selectAll:" {
                    return pasteOption
                }
                if action == "select:" {
                    return pasteOption
                }
                if action == "cut:" {
                    return pasteOption
                }
                if action == "copy:" {
                    return pasteOption
                }
                if action == "paste:" {
                    return pasteOption
                }
                return super.canPerformAction(action, withSender: sender)
            }
        }
    }
```

I want to disable cut, copy, paste on my `UITextfield` using `IBInspectable`.

Comment: In what class does this code resides in?

Comment: Seprate UITextField  https://github.com/JanakLN/TextField---IBDesignable

Answer (score 1):

You need to define your var like this:

```
@IBInspectable var pasteOption: Bool = true
```

and then override your `UITextField`'s `canPerformAction` function like this:

```
override func canPerformAction(action: Selector, withSender sender: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
    if action == "selectAll:" {
        return pasteOption
    }
    if action == "select:" {
        return pasteOption
    }
    if action == "cut:" {
        return pasteOption
    }
    if action == "copy:" {
        return pasteOption
    }
    if action == "paste:" {
        return pasteOption
    }
    return super.canPerformAction(action, withSender: sender)
}
```

By doing this you return the value of `pasteOption` for the specific actions defined in the function (which are `selectAll`, `select`, `cut`, `copy` and `paste` in this case) any time your text field opens up an edit menu.